# Replace emdash with double dash

Tags: encoding, special-characters, python-3.6

I want to replace ― back into -- 
I tried with the utf8 encodings but that doesn't work

```
string = "blablabla -- blablabla ―"
```

I want to replace the long dash (if there is one) with double hyphens. I tried it the simple way but that didn't work:

```
string= string.replace ("―", "--")
```

I also tried to encode it with utf8 and use the codes of the special characters

```
stringutf8= string.encode("utf-8")
emdash= u"\u2014"
hyphen= u"\u002D"

if emdash in stringutf8:
    stringutf8.replace(emdash, 2*hyphen)
```

Any suggestions?

I am working with text files in which sometimes apparently the two hyphens are replaced automatically with a long dash...

thanks a lot!

Comment: *" I am working with text files in which sometimes apparently the two hyphens are replaced automatically with a long dash"* Python does not sometimes replace characters in text files. There must be something else going on here. Show the code that reads the text files.

Comment: Also, are double-check that your text editor(s) consistently use the the same encoding for the same text file, and that your Python code declares that encoding when you read and write any text file. Python 3 source code ought to be saved as UTF-8, make sure your code editor does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with strings here. Strings are lists of characters. Replace the *character*, leave the encoding out of the equation.

```
string = 'blablabla -- blablabla \u2014'
emdash = '\u2014'
hyphen = '\u002D'

string2 = string.replace(emdash, 2*hyphen)
```